# Accordions, Joomla and jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, joomla, accordion

I am building a site using Joomla 3.3.6. I am using jQuery accordion to show organised information from a database. I am trying to format the look of the accordion, like to control header color text, background color etc. I have been able to remove the bullet points and control the accordion to a certain extent e.g:

```
<script>
jQuery(function()  {
    jQuery("#accordion").accordion({
        collapsible:true,
        active:false,
        icons:false
    });
});  
</script>
```

On this page of jQuery Doc http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-active it says you can access the theming by accessing the  jQuery UI CSS framework.

I would like to be able access/control this framework, but not sure how to do it through Joomla.

Sorry if this is long winded, but just trying to be detailed.
Also, learned a lot in the last couple of months about 5 different programming languages. I am kinda flying by the seat of my pants so sorry if I am asking something which seams silly.

Thanks everyone in advance, I have learned a lot from stackoverflow and I think 
it is an amazing community of people.

Comment: Why would you import a massive library such as jQueryUI for something as small as an Accordion? There are loads of small accordion jquery plugins. Or you could use the Bootstrap accordion as Bootstrap is included in Joomla 3.x

Answer (score 1):

You can just create your custom jqueryui theme at

http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/.

After download, add to your joomla theme the file jquery-ui.theme.css. Its easy add css to joomla, check this examples

https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Adding_JavaScript_and_CSS_to_the_page

http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/joomla-3/create-template/add-css-and-js